# Why is trying to console.log() array elements with Array.map() resulting in an array of undefineds?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't understand why this example produces an array of undefined at the end. I know Array.map() is supposed to run the callback function for every element in the array.

```
const musicData = [
  { artist: 'Adele', name: '25', sales: 1731000 },
  { artist: 'Drake', name: 'Views', sales: 1608000 },
  { artist: 'Beyonce', name: 'Lemonade', sales: 1554000 },
  { artist: 'Chris Stapleton', name: 'Traveller', sales: 1085000 },
  { artist: 'Pentatonix', name: 'A Pentatonix Christmas', sales: 904000 },
  { artist: 'Original Broadway Cast Recording', 
    name: 'Hamilton: An American Musical', sales: 820000 },
  { artist: 'Twenty One Pilots', name: 'Blurryface', sales: 738000 },
  { artist: 'Prince', name: 'The Very Best of Prince', sales: 668000 },
  { artist: 'Rihanna', name: 'Anti', sales: 603000 },
  { artist: 'Justin Bieber', name: 'Purpose', sales: 554000 }
];
const albumSalesStrings = musicData.map(function(album) {console.log(album.name +' by '+ album.artist + ' sold '+ album.sales + ' copies')});
console.log(albumSalesStrings);
```

The output is

```
25 by Adele sold 1731000 copies
Views by Drake sold 1608000 copies
Lemonade by Beyonce sold 1554000 copies
Traveller by Chris Stapleton sold 1085000 copies
A Pentatonix Christmas by Pentatonix sold 904000 copies
Hamilton: An American Musical by Original Broadway Cast Recording sold 820000 copies
Blurryface by Twenty One Pilots sold 738000 copies
The Very Best of Prince by Prince sold 668000 copies
Anti by Rihanna sold 603000 copies
Purpose by Justin Bieber sold 554000 copies
[
  undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined
]
```

Comment: `console.log(...)` does not return anything and therefore the mapping function returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map` exists for the function of *creating a new array* by transforming every element of another array. The expression returned from the callback on each iteration is what the new array at the given index will contain.

Since you don't return anything from the callbacks, the return value on each iteration is `undefined`, so the resulting array is filled with `undefined`.

It sounds like you don't actually want to create a new array here. Use a generic iteration method instead, like `forEach`.

```
musicData.forEach(function(album) {
  console.log(album.name +' by '+ album.artist + ' sold '+ album.sales + ' copies')
});
```

Or, if you want to both log *and* create a new array with those strings, then return the string and log the whole array afterwards:

```
const results = musicData.map(function(album) {
  return album.name +' by '+ album.artist + ' sold '+ album.sales + ' copies';
});
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` returns `undefined` so every element will become `undefined`.

You could instead use:

```
const albumSalesStrings = musicData.map(function(album) {album.name +' by '+ album.artist + ' sold '+ album.sales + ' copies'});
```

Or perhaps a bit more readably:

```
const albumSalesStrings = musicData.map((album) => `${album.name} by ${album.artist} sold ${album.sales} copies`);
```

But, if you just want to log the values, and don't need the new array, just use `forEach`:

```
const albumSalesStrings = musicData.forEach((album) => console.log(`${album.name} by ${album.artist} sold ${album.sales} copies`));
```